# Partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{x-1}{x^3+x^2}$

Tags: partial-fractions

Why the partial fraction expansion of $\frac{x-1}{x^3+x^2}$ is

$$\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{C}{x+1}$$

if I only have that $x^3 + x^2$ is the same as $x^2(x + 1)$?

Comment: Yeah, it is. You got to notice that $x^2=(x-0)^2$ though.

Comment: It is a theorem about the field of rational functions, tha't why. Anyway, when you try, you can always solve for $=the coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have $$\frac{x-1}{x^2(1+x)}=\frac {Ax+B}{x^2}+\frac C{x+1}=\frac Ax+\frac B{x^2}+\frac C{x+1}$$

The second form is often preferred for practical reasons - e.g. the first term integrates to a logarithm and the second doesn't.

Comment: In this case, A = 2, B = -1, C = -2.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for an summation of simple fractions it must be something like $$\frac{ax+b}{x^2}+\frac{c}{x+1}$$
It follows $\frac{ax+b}{x^2}$ also can be written as $$\frac{ax}{x^2}+\frac{b}{x^2}\quad\text{ or }\quad \frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x^2}$$